# Usage of "rely on"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, infinitives, subjects

Could you tell me who is doing the action of telling the time, me or my watch？

> 1. I don't sleep with a bedside alarm-clock, so when I wake up in the middle of the night, I rely on my watch to tell the time.

(https://www.watchuseek.com/thr...lity-photos.2024065/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, the text is ambiguous. But in *real-world semantics* it makes no difference - since watches aren't sentient, the only purpose (and thus, *meaning*) of the alarm going off is to notify/rouse the speaker. That meaning is the same regardless of how you choose to deconstruct the syntax.

But if you want to *force* the interpretation that has the watch as the agent, just explicitly include the object...

> *...I rely on my watch to tell **me** the time*.

...and for the other syntactic arrangement...

> *...I rely on my watch **in order** to tell the time*.

---

Note that this particular type of "syntactic, but not semantic" ambiguity isn't specific to ***rely on*** (or telling the time). It's the same with, for example...

> *I need my smartphone to record our meeting*.